# Why doesn't this KML file show up in the web version of Google Earth?

Tags: kml, google-earth, kmz

The KMZ can be obtained at https://github.com/eric-g-97477-so/wash_kmz/blob/main/wash.kmz

The structure of the zip file is simple:

```
wash/
    files/
        wash-dc.png
    wash-dc.kml
```

wash-dc.png is:

[image: wash-dc.png]

the content of the kml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Folder>
    <GroundOverlay>
      <Icon>
        <href>files/wash-dc.png</href>
      </Icon>
      <LatLonBox>
        <north>38.9098629826801456</north>
        <south>38.8880073821501711</south>
        <east>-77.0497762322933539</east>
        <west>-77.0120905091252439</west>
        <rotation>0</rotation>
      </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
  </Folder>
</kml>
```

If I double click on the kmz file, the Google Earth App I have installed on my local machine launches and successfully displays the KMZ:

[image: app version]

However, if I use the web version of Google Earth, by click on the New button and importing the kmz file, nothing shows up.

[image: web version]

I am not sure if there is something wrong with the kmz or if I am using the Web version of Google Earth incorrectly.

Comment: I can load it with [geoxml3](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) (the kmz branch): [link](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmztest_linktoB.html?lat=38.898262&lng=-77.033554&zoom=15&type=m&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kmz/wash.kmz)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kmz files can not be populated on web version.You need kml file to populate on web version.
I tried kml and its working fine on web version.

If you don't have access to GIS tool to convert kmz file you can use online tools such as [mygeodata](https://mygeodata.cloud/)